# jquery active tab on menu

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm struggling to find the solution of this for hours, but nothing seems to work no matter what I do (as much as my knowledge of javascript/jquery allows me to). So I have this jquery script that switches tabs in a search form and the code is as below:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" name="tab1">T1/a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab2">T2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content"> 
    <div id="tab1">
    TAB 1 CONTENT
    </div>

    <div id="tab2">
    TAB 2 CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

AND THE JQUERY CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
    $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

    $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
         return       
        }
        else{             
        $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
        $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
        $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
        }
    });
});
```

I tried adding a class="current" aside with the tab div name but nothing works either. I'm thinking maybe there is this click function that accepts current-tab changes only on click, but I want to make this automatic so when the second tab is active it remains active based on a 'current' class that I give. My situation is like this:
The first tab searches from English TO Italian, and the second tab searches from Italian TO English, but when I select the second option (It to En) and the page refreshes to display results the first tab is selected, so if the user wants to search 2 or more times (from Italian to english) he'd have to select second tab over and over.

If I can make it so that jquery detects the 'current' class, I can add some php to check the url parameters and properly activate the right tab. example:
if search.php?lang=`it_to_eng`, I add 'current'class to the second tab and vice versa.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem you must using **jquery.cookie** to do this. I have modified your code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var cookieName = 'tab_of';
    var cookieTab = 'tab';
    var cookieOptions = {expires: 7, path: '/'};

    $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content        
    $("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).addClass("current");
    $("#" + $.cookie(cookieTab)).fadeIn();
    if($.cookie(cookieName) == null){
        //alert($.cookie(cookieName));
        $("#tabs li:first a").attr("class","current"); // Activate first tab
        $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content
    }

    $("#tabs a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("#tabs li a").removeClass("current");
        $("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).removeClass("current");
        $.cookie(cookieName, $(this).attr("id"), cookieOptions);
        $("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).addClass("current");
        $.cookie(cookieTab, $(this).attr('name'), cookieOptions);
        $('#' + $.cookie(cookieTab)).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Each time you reload the page, the tab position will be based on the last position selected. Check out the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/597HR/

**NEW UPDATE:**

If you want session cookie will be destroyed when the user exits the browser. Change this line:

```
var cookieOptions = {expires: 7, path: '/'};
```

to

```
var cookieOptions = {path: '/'};
```

**NEW FIXING UPDATE:**

i add this code `$("#tabs li a").removeClass("current");` above `$("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).removeClass("current");`

Please clear your browser cache and reload the page. Click here to view demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/597HR/1/

Comment: hello thank you for your code, everything works fine ECXEPT one aspect. when you open the page initially, the fist page is by default selected, when I select the second tab both appear as selected  (both with red color) even though js displays the second divs content. Can you help me with this? So it'll automatically clear the first div once the second one is clicked, so they don't appear both with a red color.

PS: this problem is inexistend when you reload the page for a second time. But I worry about the fist time you open up the page and click the second tab.

Comment: my friend I think you didnt understood me. I mean The first time you visit the page, lets take this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/597HR/
(either delete your cookies/data) or open it FOR THE FIRST TIME IN a different browser. You will see that the first tab is selected (red color). NOW when you click the second tab it becomes selected(red color) and the first tab is still red, both T1 and T2 are red.
If you click the tabs a few more times they switch corrrectly but the VERY FIRST TIME they appear both as red. Hope you understand me.
now.Open jsfiddle link on another browser please.

Comment: @bornie: Oops sorry. I've been fixing the code. Check it out.

Comment: Now I'm about to check that and Im marking the answer as the correct one even though It might not work 100% properly. You have ben a huge help and I appreciate every line of code/comment you wrote.
Thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/ebomej/1/edit

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content div").hide().eq(0).show(); // show first one
    $("#tabs li").eq(0).addClass('current'); // set active one


    $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if( $(this).closest("li").hasClass('current') ){ //detection for current tab
         return;      
        }else{             
            $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
            $("#tabs li").removeClass('current');
            $(this).parent().addClass('current'); // Activate this
            $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hey, thanks for your code but I add
<li class="current" > on my desired li and put the jquery code, but nothing works still, maybe you could show some example?

Comment: @bornie you might not have seen it, but I added the demo fiddle up there in my answer